# Unable to connect to data source attendance "ODBC:attendance"

Tags: gdal, postgresql, ms-access, ogr-fdw

I'm having an issue connecting to my MS Access DB (.md file) under the  ODBC  **USER DSN** configuration in Windows.

Setting up my DSN configuration under the System DSN failed, rather USER DSN works(which to me is somewhat strange). I am able to list the layers(tables) within the **.md** file pointed to by my **DSN** configuration.

Just pointing out: My DSN is rightly configured for the right for a 64-bit Windows virtual machine.

The issue here is this:  I'm trying to create the server in my pgAdmin or psql session using the  SQL returned by running:  **ogr_fdw_info -s "ODBC:attendance" -l USERINFO**.

[image: 1]

But doing that raises a connection error that reads like so:

[image: 2]